# Spy++/UISpy, objects on windows form only exist when they are active

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, automation, ui-automation, inspector

I am working on a C# .NET application in VS2008 to automate filling out a form on another 3rd party application (no access to source). My application uses the UIAutomationClient class to do things like focus on or select elements on the form. The problem I am running into is that some of the objects that I need to work with are only visible when they have focus. For example I can only select an item from a list if the current active element is the list. My work around for this has been to send "tab" until the element I am looking for exists (sometimes there are hundreds of elements on the forms). Technically it works... But there has to be a more elegant way to make the elements visible.

Similarly, I am using the UISpy, Inspector and Spy++(32 or 64) to help identify the objects, and again they can only identify some elements when they are active. Once they lose focus they no longer show up in the tree. I assume this is because these applications most likely were developed using the same HWND search methods.

My question is, can UIAutomation identify these non-active objects? Is there a hook or alternative class that can expose them and pragmatically identify them?

Thanks,

Comment: UISpy shows everything you can do with UI Automation. Nothing more nothing less. So, if you don't see it in UISpy (with UAC enabled possibly), there is no other way. Working with UI automation is always clumsy, but it's still the way to go...

Comment: After spending a few days googling it, I kind of figured that was the case. Thanks for the input though. I always feel better about a problem I can't answer when the answer is there isn't one! :)